# Using many picker view in different action sheet?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipickerview

In my app im using 4 pickerviews in action sheet in which how can i get the particular value from the particular picker ?
in which i have used a method to get it., but i need a better way to get it., plz help me .,

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"pickerView");
    return [pickerArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (validateButton == 0){

        NSInteger temp = (row*5);
        minAsleepInt = temp;
        minAsleepLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",temp];
    }
    else if(validateButton == 1){

        noOptInt = row+1;
        noOptLable.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(validateButton == 2){

        ageTypeLable.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(validateButton == 3){

        if([pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] == @"Yes"){
            sleepLessBool = YES;
        }else{
            sleepLessBool = NO;
        }
         sleepLessLable.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

}


- (IBAction)sleepLessAction:(id)sender {

    validateButton = 3;

    pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Yes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"No"];


    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];


}

- (IBAction)ageTypeAction:(id)sender {
     validateButton = 2;

    pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Child"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Teen"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Adult"];

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];


    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}

- (IBAction)noOptAction:(id)sender {

     validateButton = 1;
    pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [pickerArray addObject:@"1"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"2"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"3"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"4"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"5"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"6"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"7"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"8"];    
    [pickerArray addObject:@"9"];

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.delegate = self;


    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];


    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

}

- (IBAction)minSleepAction:(id)sender {

         validateButton = 0;

    pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"0 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"5 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"10 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"15 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"20 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"25 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"30 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"35 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"40 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"45 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"50 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"55 Minutes"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"60 Minutes"];

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.delegate = self;


    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];


    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}


-(void)dismissActionSheet{
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Comment: Tip: Paste only the most important lines of code that you have a problem with. No one will go over your entire class to understand it if its that long.

Comment: thanks Cyprian .,i hav edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a Tag for each picker. And get the particular value from particular picker using the TAG value.

Comment: im a newbie , can u plz give me some links to for it ., i dont know how to set tag .,

Answer (score 0):

As you've done, you need to setup the following delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return PICKER_COMPONENTS;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.pickerOptions count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.pickerOptions objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Now, as far as responding to each picker's selection, I would recommend using [EAActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/EckyZero/EAActionSheetPickerDemo). It has the following optional delegate method that makes life easier

```
-(void)EAActionSheetPicker:(EAActionSheetPicker *)actionSheet
   didDismissWithSelection:(id)selection
               inTextField:(UITextField *)textField{
    // respond to your selection here
}
```

You'll just have to set it up right by hooking up each pickerView with the associated response textField. Check out the example project at the repo to see what I'm talking about.